# how do i add all the even number together?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
number = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
godlike = []


#Check closest object
def total_num(number):

    for x in number:
        if x % 2 == 0:
           godlike.append(x)
           print(x)
```

Comment: First call your function `total_num(number)` then call the sum function on the array godlike `print(sum(godlike))`

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to print a vertical list of numbers, or print the list in brackets at the end, after it has been filled?

You may want to try calling the function with a main-block like this:

```
number = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20] 
godlike = []

def total_num(num):
    for x in num:
        if x % 2 == 0:
           godlike.append(x)
           print(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    total_num(number)
```

or you can print the list godlike instead:

```
number = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20] 
godlike = []

def total_num(num):
    for x in num:
        if x % 2 == 0:
           godlike.append(x)
    print(godlike)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    total_num(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce
number = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
even_only = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, number))
sum_of_all = reduce((lambda x, y: x + y), even_only)

sum_of_all
110
```

Right now, your function is appending every even number to `godlike` and printing every `x`. I would recommend using `filter` and `reduce` if you want to get the sum of all the even values.

You can also combine `even_only` with `sum_of_all` and do it in 1 swoop. Reduce gives you some flexibility if you want to perform other operations:

```
sum_of_all = reduce((lambda x, y: x + y),filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, number))

sum_of_all
110
```

Additional option using `sum` if you're only looking for the sum:

```
sum_of_all = sum(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, number))

sum_of_all
110
```

Documentation for [Reduce and Filter](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html)

Comment: Why use `reduce()`? Why not just `sum(even_only)`?

Comment: Completely valid option as well. Will add to example.

Answer (score 0):

If your list of numbers is a complete interval of integers, just check the first element whether it is even or uneven and then sum a slice of the list.

```
>>> numbers = range(1, 21)
>>> sum(numbers[ numbers[0]%2 : : 2 ])
110
```

If your list consists of arbitrary integers, use a list comprehension.

```
>>> import random
>>> random.shuffle(numbers)
>>> sum([n for n in numbers if not n%2])
110
```

---

> Oneliners are the best liners...